# How can I create a LiveCD in <= 1G?

Tags: live-usb, livedvd

I have a 1G USB key, and CDs (which are 700M).

Most of the instructions for Ubuntu say get a 2G stick.  Many links to a USB key that is smaller are old, and point back to the Ubuntu site, which now says 2G USB key.

What are up to date instructions to make a smaller LiveCD to run?

Comment: Try [Lubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.2/release/), [Ubuntu GNOME](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04.2/release/) or [Xubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04.2/release/) instead - all have images that fit within 1G.

Comment: If the .iso is < 1 Gb it should work. Otherwise you would have to make a custom, smaller .iso

Answer (score 1):

I [agree with Bodhi](/questions/605736/how-can-i-create-a-livecd-in-1g#comment847053_605736), that you can create bootable USB media that fit only slightly more data than the size of the original ISO image. I ran Ubuntu 12.04 (~800 MB) as a live system and installed it off a 1 GiB USB drive without any issues.

Alternatively, you can use a [Minimal CD image](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) or [create your own Ubuntu remix](/q/48535/175814).